# Search box with choice of search engines

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, search

So here's the deal. I'm creating a personal start page for every time I open up a new tab or window on my browser. In my current start page, I have a search field which immediately searches in Google for me. However, many times I search for images or videos or wikipedia etc. I want to eliminate having to click on (for example) Images after my Google search. I would like to have a dropdown box next to my search, and be able to choose images, following which it would automatically search in Google Images, instead of going to standard Google.

Here's an example of what I'm thinking about:
https://dribbble.com/shots/871091-Search-Box

So the default would be blue, which will do a standard Google search. If I want to search for an image, I click the red icon in the dropdown before the search, which would automatically do a Google Image search. I'd prefer having a dropdown box, and not an option list.

Is this possible? If so, can someone help me with how to go about doing it? I am not a web developer, but I am comfortable with basic and intermediary concepts of HTML, CSS and JavaScript. Linking me some tutorials to this would be helpful, if they exist. I wasn't able to find any in my searches, but maybe I've been using the wrong terms.

Cheers.

Comment: What have you tried?  You might want to check out [how to ask a question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) .

Answer (score 0):

The feature you're looking for is called search engines. You can map a keyword to a search engine.

For instance I can type `y nyancat` in the omnibar to search for *"nyancat"* on YouTube.

Similarly you can set one up for google images.